# Problem in converting the code form vb.net to c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

VB Code:

```
Public Event PropertyChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
  If PropertyChangedEvent IsNot Nothing Then
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
  End If
End Sub
```

Converted C# code

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged;

public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);

public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (PropertyChangedEvent != null) {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

Error is:

> Error 1 The name 'PropertyChangedEvent' does not exist in the current context

Comment: General note, download and install refelector. Invalubale when converting from/to VB and C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event is called "PropertyChanged", not "PropertyChangedEvent".
Also, the event is explicitly implemented, which means, you'd have to use this:
`((INotifyPropertyChanged)this).PropertyChanged` instead of `PropertyChanged` to access the event.
And as Oded pointed out, the code checks twice for the event. You can remove one of those checks.

Comment: +1 - Yep. And there is even an additional nested `if` clause dealing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use explicit interface implementation but just make it a public method.

Or cast `this` to the interface to call the handler. `((INotifyPropertyChanged)this).PropertyChanged`